# Error converting data type varchar to numeric. in Below sql Querys

Tags: sql-server

```sql
SELECT   ltrim(flexid + ' - ' + descr + ' ($' + max_deduct + ' deductible)') descr, 
                            flexid 
                        FROM [MHCSI].[FLEX_PLAN] 
                        WHERE groupno =  '0000080002' ORDER BY flexid;
```

Comment: Presumably one of your columns, `flexid`, `descr` or `max_deduct` (I suspect this one) is a `numeric`, and thus your query fails, as (for starters) neither `' - '` or `'deductible)'`are a valid `numeric` value.

Comment: The issue most likely is that SQL Server is assuming your use of `+` and a mix of numeric columns (presumably max_deduct) means you want to do math. Try using `CAST(max_deduct AS nvarchar())` in the query instead.

Comment: `+` in T-SQL is both a concatenation operator *and* a unary addition operator, @SchmitzIT . Which is it interpreted as depends on the value on either side of the operator. For example, `'1' + '2'` returns `'12'`, as both are `varchar` values. `'1' + 3` returns `4`, as `'1'` is implicitly converted to an `int` first. `'1' + '2' + 3` would return `15`, as `'1' + '2' = '12'`, which is then implicitly converted to an `int` in the next operation; giving `15`.

Comment: @Larnu I'm aware. I ran into this more than once myself :) I typically use `CONCAT` to string things together, just to avoid confusion. I guess my "do math" explanation wasn't very well chosen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that SQL Server assumed you want to perform a mathematical function to the `max_deduct` column. Because what you **really** want to do is just concatonate it to the rest of the string value that you are building, the easiest solution would be to make sure SQL Server understands you want to use the value of the column as a test value. You can do this by explicitly casting the value to a text-string.

Try rewriting your statement to this:

```
SELECT   
     ltrim(flexid + ' - ' + descr + ' ($' + CAST(max_deduct AS nvarchar(50)) + ' deductible)') descr
     , flexid 
FROM 
     [MHCSI].[FLEX_PLAN] 
WHERE 
     groupno =  '0000080002' ORDER BY flexid;
```

Comment: `CAST(max_deduct AS nvarchar())` isn't valid syntax, you forgot to include a value for the length.

Comment: @Larnu - Cheers. I didn't test the code. Well caught :) I updated the answer.

Comment: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: @ImranHusain - Add `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to one of the sides of the equal operation. I.e. `WHERE a.foo = b.bar COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` or `WHERE a.foo COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = b.bar`. 

More info: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/